# Getting GUID of group with IADs interface

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, active-directory

I'm using the following C++ code to get all groups for a user:
(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746342(v=vs.85).aspx. I just added a few liens to get the group GUID as well)

```
HRESULT CheckUserGroups(IADsUser *pUser)
{
    IADsMembers *pGroups;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    hr = pUser->Groups(&pGroups);
    pUser->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    IUnknown *pUnk;
    hr = pGroups->get__NewEnum(&pUnk);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    pGroups->Release();

    IEnumVARIANT *pEnum;
    hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IEnumVARIANT, (void**)&pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    pUnk->Release();

    // Enumerate.
    BSTR bstr;
    VARIANT var;
    IADs *pADs;
    ULONG lFetch;
    IDispatch *pDisp;

    VariantInit(&var);
    hr = pEnum->Next(1, &var, &lFetch);
    while (hr == S_OK)
    {
        if (lFetch == 1)
        {
            pDisp = V_DISPATCH(&var);
            pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IADs, (void**)&pADs);
            pADs->get_Name(&bstr);
            printf("Group belonged: %S\n", bstr);
            SysFreeString(bstr);
            pADs->get_GUID(&bstr);
            printf("Group guid: %S\n", bstr);
            SysFreeString(bstr);
            pADs->Release();
        }
        VariantClear(&var);
        pDisp = NULL;
        hr = pEnum->Next(1, &var, &lFetch);
    };
    hr = pEnum->Release();
    return S_OK;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CComPtr<IADsUser> pUser;
    std::wstring ADpathName = std::wstring(L"WinNT://domain/user");
    if( ADsGetObject(ADpathName.c_str(), IID_IADsUser, (void**)&pUser) == S_OK )
    {
        CheckUserGroups(pUser);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the GUID for all groups is the same and doesn't reflect the real group GUID. why is that?

Comment: `CheckUserGroups()` has no business calling `pUser->Release()`, that is `main`'s responsibility after `CheckUserGroups()` exits. Also, `CheckUserGroups()` is leaking `pGroups` if `get__NewEnum()` fails, and is leaking `pUnk` if `QueryInterface(IEnumVARIANT)` fails. Learn to use smart pointers like `CComPtr` instead of calling `Release()` manually. And your `while` loop is not doing any error handling at all. And your `if (lFetch == 1)` check is redundant since `lFetch` will always be 1` when `Next(1)` returns `S_OK`. `Next()` will return `S_FALSE` when it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question... (this sample is copied it from MSDN)